# using excel divide any value in a col by 1000, then multp new value by 10 & upd a running total cell, while leaving the orig value alone

Tags: excel

For example if I enter a `2000` in `B3`, I would like that number divided by `1000`, then multiplied by `10`, and have the new value added to a running total.  ie `(2000/1000 * 10=20)`

```
RunningTotal = 20
```

For clarity, if I enter `8000` in `B4`, then I would like to `(8000/1000 * 10 = 80 )`

```
RunningTotal = 100
```

Comment: Where do you want to see the result, in the input cell?
When does this operation should be triggered? By hiting ENTER?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

```
(x / 1000 * 10) + (y / 1000 * 10) = (x + y)/1000 * 10
```

So the equation for your running total cell only needs to be:

```
=SUM(B3:B10)/1000*10
```

Assuming `B3:B10` is the appropriate range for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply record a macro:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-macro-HP005204711.aspx

So you do everything you would like to calculate "by hand" while recording a macro and then you can call it at any time you want to execute.

Answer (score 0):

equation formula

```
(x / 1000 * 10) + (y / 1000 * 10) = (x + y)/1000 * 10    
=    
(x+y) * 0.01     
= 
sum(B3:B?) * 0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks for the replies.
```

I will be entering in values into col B(B3,B4...B200 etc.). The running total value will be displayed in it's own cell.  The running total value will be updated upon save or enter. The orig value entered into the B column cells should remain the same.

The formula or calculation should occur anytime a value is entered into a cell within col B.

So if I have any number of values in col B, what I am expecting is:

```
1000/1000 * 10 = 10 
5000/1000 * 10 = 60
8000/1000 * 10 = 140 etc.
```

If I use a separate cell to hold the runningTotal value, for ex K2...formula is: =C3/1000*10 ...how can I repeat this formula for subsequent cells in col B, but update the cell K2?

Must I use a holding column for each corresponding value entered in col B, then add the value to the K2 cell?

Ah, yes, I have managed to get it working by using a holding cell.  if there is a more elegant approach, I am open to suggestions.

thanks for your advice.